# What introductory and advanced textbooks on cognitive psychology are recommended?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request

What introductory and advanced textbooks on cognitive psychology are recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, [book recommendation](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/943/7001) questions don't fit the scope of this site, especially one as broad as this.  This (closed) question does have an answer: [best book for cognitive science](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9146/7001).

Answer (score 1):

1. Algom, D. (Eds). (1992). Psychophysical Prospects to Cognition, Amsterdam:Elsevier.
2. Durso, F. T. (2007). Handbook of Applied Cognition (2nd Ed). New West Sussex : Wiley & Sons.
3. Esgate, A. et al. (2005). An Introduction to Applied Cognitive Psychology. Psychology Press: New York. - **A good book to start with the basics of Cognitive Psychology.**
4. Galotti, K. M., Fernandes, M., Fugelsang, J., Stolz, J. (2009). Cognitive Psychology: In and Out of the laboratory (First Canadian Edition). Canada: Cengage Learning. - **Bible of Cognitive Psychology along with interesting demonstrations and web resources at the end of each chapter.**
5. Levitin D. J. (2002). Foundations of cognitive psychology: core readings. MIT Press. - **Foundation level**
6. Sternberg, R. J. (Ed.) (2000). Handbook of intelligence. New York: Cambridge University Press.
7. Sternberg, R. J. (2009). Applied Cognitive Psychology: Perceiving Learning and Remembering. Australia: Cengage Learning.- **Advanced level**

I hope these references help:)